# [Map] question about its basic 2d map structure~

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I have some questions about the 2d map built by the map_server from the Nav_msgs::Occupancy Grid.
There are few points unclear.

a)could I assume the origin of the map represent the (0,0) point, the lower-left corner of the 2d map?

b)could I assume that map.info.width contains the information of size of ENTIRE map?

c) could I assume the resolution is in meter/cell?

```
***Occupancy grid structure*:**
# This represents a 2-D grid map, in which each cell represents the probability of
# occupancy.


Header header 

#MetaData for the map
MapMetaData info

# The map data, in row-major order, starting with (0,0).  Occupancy
# probabilities are in the range [0,100].  Unknown is -1.
int8[] data

--------------------------------
***MapMetaData structure***
# This hold basic information about the characterists of the OccupancyGrid

# The time at which the map was loaded
time map_load_time
# The map resolution [m/cell]
float32 resolution
# Map width [cells]
uint32 width
# Map height [cells]
uint32 height
# The origin of the map [m, m, rad].  This is the real-world pose of the
# cell (0,0) in the map.
geometry_msgs/Pose origin
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73525/%5Bmap%5D-question-about-its-basic-2d-map-structure%7E/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-08-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on 2017-06-27**:
Hi, can i do mapping only with ultrasonic sensor range and IMU ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

a) yes, b) width and height, c) yes.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2